# Is there any way to write function "def" by using apply and lambda

Tags: python, pandas

I am quite new in this. I just want to write beutiful code. Right now i am extracting string from a column (URL Column) and defining new column to add the extracted value. I am extracting the string based on dictionary. Here is my code:

Df Sample:

[image]

```
def conv_attribution_brand_keyword(domain, url):
    
    if domain in dict_brand_keywords.keys():
        
        for keyword in dict_brand_keywords[domain]:
            if keyword in url:
                  return(keyword)
```

Dictionary:

```
brand_dict = {'bmw': ['/1er/', '/m/', '/2er/', '/3er/', '/4er/', '/5er/', '/6er/', '/7er/', '/8er/', '/x/', '/z4/', '/bmw-i/'], 'audi': ['/a1/', '/a3/', '/a4/', '/a5/', '/a6/', '/a7/', '/a8/', '/q2/', '/q3/', '/q5/', '/q7/', '/q8/', '/tt/', '/r8/', '/tron/'], 'mercedes-benz': ['/c-class/', '/e-class/', '/s-class/', '/gle/', '/cla/', '/cls/', '/glc/', '/amg-gt/', '/a-class/', '/sl/', '/slc/', '/b-class/', '/eqc/', '/g-class/', '/gla/', '/glb/', '/gls/', '/v-class/', '/x-class/'], 'skoda-auto': ['/fabia/', '/scala/', '/kamiq/', '/octavia-neu/', '/karoq/', '/kodiaq/', '/superb/']}
```

Is there any way to reduce these number of lines.

I just want to redunce lines and want to get output where it extract keyword based on dictionary value.

Comment: BTW, you never have to do `if anything in dictionary.keys():`. Just `if anything in dictionary:` is enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make it a little bit shorter:

```
def conv_attribution_brand_keyword(domain, url):
    for keyword in dict_brand_keywords.get(domain, []):
        if keyword in url:
            return keyword
```

I think this is OK :)

Answer (score 1):

You can (at least in Python 3.8), but you probably don't want to.

```
conv_attribution_brand_keyword = (lambda domain, url: rv
                                    if any((rv:=keyword) in url
                                           for keyword in dict_brand_keywords.get(domain, []))
                                    else None)
```

(Multiple lines for display purposes only; all newlines could be removed.)

(There are hacks that will do the same thing prior to Python 3.8, without the assignment expression operator `:=`, but they look even worse.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you explain a bit, what is rv? Is there any special purpose for this?

Comment: `rv` is short for "return value". The assignment expression assigns the value of `keyword` to `rv` each time you evaluate the expression `keyword in url`. Because `any` short-circuits and exits as soon as a true value is found, `rv` serves as a witness to the value that made `any` return `True`.